# Alternative to base64 Encoded Image sources (E-Mail Signatures)

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am trying to generate email signatures for my entire company so I am using a script to fill in an [HTML template](https://gist.github.com/TKerstiens/dd948e1ec82e073bed30fbef859a8a16) with each individual's information and generating an HTML file that I would like to use for the signature. The generation of the HTML works fine and I can load the HTML into chrome and it displays 100% correctly.

I would prefer to not have to host these images somewhere at the moment and would like them to be embedded in the e-mail. We can achieve this by using outlook on each individuals machine to create the signature by hand, but again we want to avoid that. Ideally, we will generate these templates and then automatically put these files on each employee's computer so all we have to do is select the signature from outlook.

The problem we are having is that when we do this, the image does not load. It seems that outlook won't allow base64 encoded images? I've tried to work around this by trying to attach the image to the email and then referencing it, but this doesn't seem to work either. I used [this template](https://gist.github.com/TKerstiens/ca4cfb2400c4516f7c256c1208e2d483). I got the boundary from a test email I sent myself, but I don't even know if this is a good way to go about this either.

In short, is there a way to create an .htm file for outlook signatures that includes the image inside the .htm file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External image file that will be added as an attachment is the only way - Word (which renders HTML messages in Outlook) does not support base64 embedded images.

Try to create a new signature with an image in Outlook and see how they reference the images.